# Trying to add two return values into one shortcode PHP WordPress (total number of posts and pages)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am new to php, please help.
I am using this shortcode to show total number of published posts (400), it works fine. If I change ('post') to ('page') it shows total number of published pages (100) just as fine. I am trying to show total number of posts and pages (500) using one shortcode. Is it possible to add the two results and display as one total result?

```
function published_posts($atts) {
return wp_count_posts('post')->publish;
}
add_shortcode('posts_count', 'published_posts');
```

Comment: try  to return array

Comment: how? could you help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you're attempting to do is possible. Simply assign the value of `wp_count_posts()` for both posts and pages to variables and then add them together in the return statement.

Example:

```
function published_posts( $atts ) {
    $post_count = wp_count_posts( 'post' )->publish;
    $page_count = wp_count_posts( 'page' )->publish;

    return $post_count + $page_count;
}
add_shortcode( 'posts_count', 'published_posts' );
```

While this will work, I'm not convinced it's the most efficient approach you could take. It's making two trips to the database for information which could be retrieved in one. That being said, `wp_count_posts()` won't accept an array of post types so you'd likely have to code something from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so much Nathan! This works excellent! I will use it until I find different solution in order not to make 2 trips to the database.